# Create a default wordpress menu with all pages without actually creating one in the menu panel

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I know this can be done but i've not got a clue how.

Rather than going into wordpress and creating a menu, I simply want to show all the pages that exists.

i.e. If I go into the menu panel and create a new menu, I then add pages 1, 2, 3 and 4, the menu will then show those 4 pages but I actually have 7 pages in wordpress.

So rather than manually adding all 7 pages, I want to show all pages as default

Here's my menu so far

```
<nav class="indent-right"> 
  <?php
wp_nav_menu(
array (
    'menu'            => 'main-menu',
    'container'       => FALSE,
    'container_id'    => FALSE,
    'menu_class'      => '',
    'menu_id'         => FALSE,
    'depth'           => 1,
    'walker'          => new Description_Walker
)
);
?>
</nav>
```

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following to invoke the menu:

```
<?php wp_page_menu( $args ); ?>
```

Change the args as needed:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'depth'       => 0,
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order, post_title',
    'menu_class'  => 'menu',
    'include'     => '',
    'exclude'     => '',
    'echo'        => true,
    'show_home'   => false,
    'link_before' => '',
    'link_after'  => '' );
?>
```

By default, all pages will be shown. [Read more here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_page_menu).